# Concatenating PHP and JS while echoing

Tags: javascript, php, escaping, concatenation

I have JS with an options var like so :

```
$output .= 
        '<script type="text/javascript">
         // <![CDATA[

                var options = {
                        render: "canvas", 
                        size: "100",
                        radius: "0.5",
                        };

         // ]]>
         </script>';
```

But I need to output it ( echo ) with PHP variables and it can not be in a separated file, So I did the output using normal concatenation with a point `.` e.g. `'.$var.'`but since my JS needs double quotes `"` I had put them also into the mix resulting in double-single quote sequence .

```
var options = {
        render: "'.$q_render.'", // Canvas, Div ,Image
        size: "'.$q_size.'",
        radius: "'. $q_corner_r.'",
        };
```

And it works as far as my tests goes .

The plot thickens , when I need the specific value of `$q_corner_r` to be multiplied by a factor :

```
var options = {
        render: "'.$q_ender.'", // Canvas, Div ,Image
        size: "'.$q_size.'",
        radius: "'. ($q_corner_r )* 3 .'",
        };
```

Which also works . 
But the real problem is that I needed to be a decimal value and thus multiple by a decimal factor .

```
var options = {
        render: "'.$q_ender.'", // Canvas, Div ,Image
        size: "'.$q_size.'",
        radius: "'. ($q_corner_r )* 0.3 .'",
        };
```

At this point , PHP throws an error , because for all it knows, the decimal point in `0.3` is actually an `end concatenation` point.

my layman solution to the problem was to wrap the problem in `json_encode()` and send it to battle naked and defenseless.

```
radius: "'. json_encode( ($q_corner_r )* 0.1 ) .'",
```

which , very surprisingly, works ok.

So everything works now ( don´t panic ) - but my doubt remains.

How should I handle this situation ? ( I know I *CAN* do `$qr_corner_r = ($qr_corner_r )* 0.1` in PHP before the JS .. but *SHOULD I* ? )

It is only for pure luck ( or stupidity, or a combination of both ) that my code works .

Is there any other solution / method adequate for these situations ?

Are we merely observing a simply bad "wrong escaping" case ? ( or no-escaping-at-all in my case )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is assuming that JavaScript needs it's values wrapped with quotes, this is only required for string values, for numbers — especially ones you are going to use in calculations — you should leave them unquoted.

```
$output .= 
  '<script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[

    var options = {
      render: "canvas", 
      size: 100,
      radius: (' . $q_corner_r . ' * 0.3)
    };

   // ]]>
   </script>';
```

That way JavaScript will interpret them as type `Number`, allowing you to perform mathematical calculations without have to rely on JavaScript casting string values back to numbers which can give uncertain results.

As a rule, if you are finding that you are getting confused with escaping, or multiple levels of quotes it is better to rethink your approach. The above could be easily handled by way of `json_encoding` an entire PHP object, and performing the multiplication on the PHP side.

```
$data = (object) array(
  'render' => 'canvas',
  'size' => 100,
  'radius' => ($q_corner_r * 0.3),
);

$output .= 
  '<script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[

    var options = ' . json_encode($data) . '

   // ]]>
   </script>';
```

Comment: Thanks, This is actually great answer . It would indeed be much better for me to pass the whole options as an object ..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to change your code to look like it does below:

```
var options = {
    render: "'.$qr_ender.'", // Canvas, Div ,Image
    size: "'.$q_size.'",
    radius: "'. ($q_corner_r * 0.3) .'",
    };
```

You added the `()` but did so only around the variable, making them useless.

In effect, you are performing math, so by adding the `()` you are isolating that piece of math to be calculated before the rest, just the same as in any other math situation.

Comment: Except with JSON-encoding everything.

Comment: the JSON encoding in his code doesnt actually do anything, it just causes a seperate execution scope due to the `()` of it. (JSON encoding a number gives a number)

Answer (score -1):

try that:

```
$var = ($q_corner_r* 0.3);
$str ="
      var options = {
                render: "'.$q_ender.'", // Canvas, Div ,Image
                size: "'.$q_size.'",
                radius: "'. $var .'",
                };
";
```

Comment: Did you even check to notice that the whole thing is inside a php string already?? how the heck is `<?php $output='... "'.(<?php...` supposed to not crash and burn?

Comment: not to mention that I already wrote in the question that I can do it in PHP before the JS `$qr_corner_r = ($qr_corner_r * 0.3)`

Comment: bad formated code examples... made me confused ... sry! just do it before? why hustle around with unreadable concatenations?